# Unable to play last tracks of mp3 cd

Tags: cd, mp3, cp, cd-ripping

for some reason I am not able to play the last tracks of some mp3 cds (of a audiobook I purchased). I am able to play the first tracks of the CD. Therefore it couldn't be a problem with missing codecs. I am also able to play other MP3 files on my laptop.

At first I assumed, that this is because of a production error on a specific CD. Unfortunately this problem seems to occur with every CD of the audiobook. So I think a problem with the CDs is very unlikely...

I am not even able to copy the last tracks with `cp` to my personal folder:

```
cp: error reading '386 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend '/home/flammi/test2/386 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: error reading '387 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend '/home/flammi/test2/387 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: error reading '388 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend '/home/flammi/test2/388 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: error reading '389 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend '/home/flammi/test2/389 Der zweite Krieg beginnt.mp3': Input/output error
```

Does somebody have an idea what the problem here is or has someone else experienced a problem like this before?

Comment: When the OS encounters a serious I/O error on a mounted device, it limits access to read-only by default. Please check/post your `dmesg` logs to get info on what the actual error(s) were.